# SyntaxError: Unexpected token e in JSON at position 1

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

What's wrong with below code? I keep getting following error.
The response from ajax is plain text, for instance "Hello world". Does $http.get() expects json response?

> angular.js:13550 SyntaxError: Unexpected token t in JSON at position 1
>       at Object.parse (native)
>       at uc (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js:17:36)
>       at ac (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js:91:229)

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0-rc2/angular-material.min.css">


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0-rc2/angular-material.min.js"></script>




<script>
    var resourceApp = angular.module("resourceApp", [ "ngMaterial" ])
            .controller('resourceController', function resourceController($scope, $http) {
                $scope.processForm = function() {
                    $http.get("test")
                        .then(function(response) {
                            console.log(response.data);

                        });
                };
            });
</script>
</head>
<body ng-app="resourceApp" ng-controller="resourceController">

    <button ng-click="processForm()">Submit</button>
    <pre>{{response}}</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the data returned by your server? Hint: it's probably not (valid) JSON.

Comment: yes, it is just plain text, updated the question

Comment: Is your server setting the `Content-Type` response header to indicate JSON?

Comment: Yes, it was `application/json`. But I changed it to `plain/text` and still see the same error

Comment: Answered below, check 1) Your AngularJS header configuration, 2) Your server configuration and 3) that "test" is a valid route in your server, that delivers a plain text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For your second question**
Not necessarily. You should check both in your server and your front-end configuration that you are actually allowed to receive plain text as a response.

[The official $http documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) will help you about setting your header correctly, while I let you check for your server configuration as well.

**For the first one**

Is "test" a valid route ? It seems that $http tries to get "test" as a plain text, and not the resource which is stored behind "test", as the firt incorrect character is 't'. Otherwise (if it is a valid route), please refer on the above-mentioned answer.

**EDIT**

When calling $http (even in *localhost*), you must mention the full route to your resource. Here, you cannot directly call ("test"), it interprets it as a plain "test" request. Try calling:

`$http.get('localhost:[your port]/test').then { ...what you need to do... });`

**SECOND EDIT**

`text/plain` and `plain/text` makes a difference when configuringn, be careful ! This fixed the asker's problem.

Comment: Try accessing your server with the following syntax:
`$http.get('localhost:[your port]/test')`. I think this should solve the problem.

Comment: As someone downvoted me I cannot comment your question anymore, but I'll do it here. If you are getting the same error (`angular.js:13550 SyntaxError: Unexpected token t in JSON at position 1 at Object.parse (native)`) and your server sends _plain/text_, it means that your AngularJS application expects JSON. As I linked you before, I advise you reading [this page](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) which covers effectively headers and content type (official documentation).

Comment: By the way, as I also read through, try `text/plain` instead of `plain/text`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110977/discussion-between-yassine-badache-and-sidgate).