# SyntaxError: Unexpected token e in JSON at position 1 || 400 Bad Request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vue.js, axios

I'm trying to submit form data in my Vue app. I have an express backend API. The endpoint I'm trying to post to works perfectly on postman. I keep getting either "SyntaxError: Unexpected token g in JSON at position 0" or "400: Bad Request"

I have tried to use JSON.parse(this.description). I have tried it without parsing this.description.

In my axios config file, I tried changing the response header to "application/json" in my axios response interceptor. I tried it without doing that as well.

Here is the form

```
<v-dialog v-model="dialog" persistent max-width="600px">
      <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
        <v-tooltip top>
          <v-btn small fab color="white" dark v-on="on" slot="activator">
            <v-icon color="primary">add</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
          <span>Add Task</span>
        </v-tooltip>
      </template>
      <v-card>
        <v-card-title>
          <span class="headline">Add Task</span>
        </v-card-title>
        <v-card-text>
          <v-form>
            <v-textarea v-model="description" label="Description"></v-textarea>
          </v-form>
        </v-card-text>
        <v-card-actions>
          <v-spacer></v-spacer>
          <v-btn color="blue darken-1" flat @click="dialog = false">Close</v-btn>
          <v-btn color="blue darken-1" flat @click="addTask">Save</v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
      </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
```

Here is the axios request

```
methods: {
    ...mapActions(["fetchTasks"]),
    addTask() {
      console.log(this.description);
      axios
        .post("tasks", JSON.parse(this.description))
        .then(response => {
          dialog = "false";
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
  }
```

Here is my axios config file

```
"use strict";

import Vue from 'vue';
import axios from "axios";
import store from '../store';

// Full config:  https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config
// axios.defaults.baseURL = process.env.baseURL || process.env.apiUrl || '';
// axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = '';
axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';

let config = {
  baseURL: "http://localhost:3000/",
  timeout: 60 * 1000, // Timeout
  withCredentials: false, // Check cross-site Access-Control
};

const _axios = axios.create(config);

_axios.interceptors.request.use(
  function (config) {
    // Do something before request is sent
    let token = store.getters.getToken;

    if (token) {
      config.headers.common.Authorization = token;
    }

    return config;
  },
  function (error) {
    // Do something with request error
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

// Add a response interceptor
_axios.interceptors.response.use(
  function (response) {
    // Do something with response data
    return response;
  },
  function (error) {
    // Do something with response error
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

Plugin.install = function (Vue, options) {
  Vue.axios = _axios;
  window.axios = _axios;
  Object.defineProperties(Vue.prototype, {
    axios: {
      get() {
        return _axios;
      }
    },
    $axios: {
      get() {
        return _axios;
      }
    },
  });
};

Vue.use(Plugin)

export default Plugin;
```

Here is the endpoint

```
router.post('/tasks', auth, async (req, res) => {
  const task = new Task({
    ...req.body,
    owner: req.user._id
  });

  try {
    await task.save();
    res.status(201).send(task);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).send();
  }
});
```

Here is the Headers data under Google Chrome's Network tab

[image: Imgur]

Comment: What data-type is your backend expecting in the request body? JSON or `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`?

Comment: It's expecting JSON. When I change the content-type to "application/json", I get 400 Bad Request

Comment: Then why are you setting Axios to send `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`? I don't understand your use of `JSON.parse(this.description)` either. Are you expecting your users to type valid JSON into the _Description_ field? What fields are you wanting to send in the request JSON? What **exactly** is your backend expecting?

Comment: Ahhh. Bonehead of a mistake. Backend is expecting an object. I wasn't passing an object into the post request.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SyntaxError: Unexpected token e in JSON at position 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37023257/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-e-in-json-at-position-1)

Answer (score 1):

If your API is expecting a JSON request (per your comment) you will need to change your axios config from:

```
axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
```

to:

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
```

For good measure I would also recommend these, assuming your expecting to receive JSON in return:

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['Accept'] = 'application/json';
```

And to explicitly assert the requested with header:

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XmlHttpRequest';
```

In regards to the axios post call, assuming this.description is the text that was entered into an input field or textarea you will need to build the JSON request like this:

```
.post("tasks", {
  'description': this.description
})
```

OR set a data object such as:

```
data () {
    return {
        formFields: {
            description: null
        }
    }
}
```

And update the v-model to:

```
<v-textarea v-model="formFields.description" label="Description"></v-textarea>
```

and then you can use:

```
.post("tasks", this.formFields.description)
```

Comment: I'm still getting a 400 (Bad Request) error

POST http://localhost:3000/tasks 400 (Bad Request)
AddTaskForm.vue?09b5:47 Error: Request failed with status code 400
    at createError (createError.js?2d83:16)
    at settle (settle.js?467f:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js?b50d:59)

Comment: You will need to post your API code as the error is being derived on the API not handling the response correctly. OR it is requiring something you are not providing.

Comment: Also can you post a picture of the response tab?

Comment: According to the server it is sending back text/html not JSON

Comment: API error message: SyntaxError: Unexpected token " in JSON at position 0

The endpoint is in my original post.

Comment: Your request body is empty in your image, was it cut off? what is the output of: console.log(this.description);

Comment: Here are the response headers on postman:

X-Powered-By →Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin →*
Content-Type →application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length →194
ETag →W/"c2-imTfszxUgdj4WECg8lIE+aqOlj0"
Date →Tue, 18 Jun 2019 03:14:57 GMT
Connection →keep-alive

Comment: console.log(this.description) logs what was put into the form

Comment: I realize that is the input, but seeing as your request body is empty (not being populated in the request that you posted in the IMGUR) it would be beneficial to know what it is outputting to the console. Please update the console log statement to the following and post back `console.log(JSON.parse(this.description))`

Comment: I was making a bonehead mistake. Backend was expecting an object. I wasn't passing an object into the post request.

Comment: The default Axios headers for `Content-type` and `Accept` are sufficient in OP's case. They should not be overwriting them at all

Comment: @Milad glad you we're able to get your issue resolved.

Comment: @Phil wasn't much to go on to start with... explicitly setting defaults MAY not be needed/required but surely explicitly setting defaults in the Axios plugin (or any plugin for that matter) does not hurt anything and an argument could be made that it could help a front end dev that follows you in the code base later to better understand the expected behavior of the API and VueJS code base.